# .scn model rotated by 90 degrees after conversion from .dae

Tags: swift, xcode, 3d, ios11, scenekit

I opened a `.dae` in Xcode to show it in SceneKit. Everything worked fine.

To add some nodes, I converted it automatically with Xcode to `.scn` format.

However, when I now run the app, the model is rotated by 90 degrees, probably because the y axis is orientated differently.

Is there an option, to fix this, without manually rotating everything back by 90 degrees?

Sure, I could set `Euler angle` for XZY 270 degrees. However, that's no clean solution, since I would also have to adjust the params for any operations I'm doing with the model. Is there a way, to set this 270 degrees to new default = 0 degrees?

Answer (score 1):

The `rotation`, `eulerAngles`, and `orientation` properties – all affect the rotational aspect of the node’s transform property. Any change to one of these properties is reflected in the others.

```
var rotation: SCNVector4 { get set }
var eulerAngles: SCNVector3 { get set }
var orientation: SCNQuaternion { get set }
```

Try to change the order of components (xyz) in vector matches (`eulerAngles`) the axes of rotation. For macOS `xyz` fields are of type `CGFloat` and for iOS they are of type `Float`.

The order of components in this vector matches the axes of rotation:

1. Pitch (`X` component) is the rotation about the node’s `X-axis`.
2. Yaw (`Y` component) is the rotation about the node’s `Y-axis`.
3. Roll (`Z` component) is the rotation about the node’s `Z-axis`.

SceneKit applies these rotations relative to the node’s pivot property **in the reverse order** of the components:

1. first **Roll**,
2. then **Yaw**,
3. then **Pitch**.

The best solution is to prepare your 3D model with **`ZYX rotation order`** in 3D package.